# Is there an inefficiency in for loops using iterators?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, iterator

In several examples, for loops with iterators are done like this:

```
for (list<MyClass>::iterator i = MyList.begin(); i != MyList.end(); ++i) {
    (*i).Draw();
}
```

Every loop, an iterator object is created at the compare part (`i != MyList.end()`), no? Isn't this extra work?

Comment: It might be less extra work than you think; optimizers are very good at removing unnecessary code.

Comment: It would be if compilers did exactly what we wrote - but I don't think it's a bad question, quite the opposite.

Comment: You are allowed to modify a `std::list` while iterating over it, so the meaning of the loop could be different if you retrieve `end()` only once. If you do not intend anything like that, then don't use this style of iteration, use a range-for instead: `for(auto& x : MyList) { x.Draw(); }`. It is in most cases the better choice, for style reasons and avoidance of typos alone. It also evaluates the `end()` iterator only once.

Comment: "*Isn't this extra work?*" Yes, but such iterators are meant to be cheap to create/destroy/copy in the first place.

Comment: @user17732522 "*You are allowed to modify a `std::list` while iterating over it (but not a `std::vector`)*" - you can modify a vector while iterating it, as long as you pay attention to the new iterator that `vector::erase()` returns (same with a `std::list`, BTW). That is not possible in a `range-for` loop, but can be accounted for in a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I removed the part of the comment. I wanted to explain that it is more difficult with a vector, but didn't have enough space.

Comment: The problem isn't iterators because you can always code this `list<MyClass>::iterator endi = MyList.end(); for (list<MyClass>::iterator i = MyList.begin(); i != endi; ++i) {` but I agree, let the compiler worry about this kind of thing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau _""Isn't this extra work?" Yes"_ - It _may_ be. Compilers are pretty nifty and if they recognize a pattern they've been optimized for, it may be _less_ work - benchmarking required. :)

Comment: @john that can be simplified to `for (auto i = MyList.begin(), endi = MyList.end(); i != endi; ++i)` but yeah, a `range-for` is better for that

Comment: It should be noted that since C++17 the standard has mandated that the end iterator be cached in a [ranged base for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) because in general a compiler may not be able to inline the call.  This is for cases where the function lives in a separate TU.  For standard containers it wont make a difference and the compiler is perfectly able to perform the inlining optimization.

Comment: If you want to improve efficiency, store `MyList.end()` into a `const` iterator variable.  This allows the `for` loop to compare iterators without having to call a function every iteration.  If you have compiled at higher optimizations, the compiler may do this for you.

Comment: note that instead of `(*i).Draw();` you can just do `i->Draw();`